# Android Architecture: Using multiple ContentProviders and onUpgrade event

Tags: android, upgrade, android-contentprovider, sqliteopenhelper

My application has two database tables: `Products` and `ShoppingCard`. So I created a `ProductContentProvider` and `ShoppingCardContentProvider`. Each `ContentProvider` invokes in its `onCreate()` method a private class that is child of `SQLiteOpenHelper`.

1. From my point of view I would make a global static variable `DATABASE_VERSION` in a **separated** *ConfigBean* that is responsible for **both** content providers. So if I update that all tables are updated.
   => That does not work. Simply the onUpdate event is never fired.
2. If you specify a `DATABASE_VERSION` in each content provider, but with **different** version numbers in each content provider
   => That does not work. Also it makes no sense, from my point of view, because the paramater in `SQLiteOpenHelper` is called `DATABASE_VERSION` **not** `TABLE_VERSION`. So in other words, you cannot update any table without updating/throwing an event on all *onUpgrade* listeners.
3. If you specify a `DATABASE_VERSION` in each content provider, but with **equal** version numbers in each content provider.
   => That works.

**Question:**

Why can't you make the `DATABASE_VERSION` a public static variable outside to handle upgrades globaly, or am I completely on the wrong path with my architecture?

Answer (score 1):

The solution to my problem was to create a **base class** to both content providers. This class holds the only instance of SQLiteOpenHelper. This also ensures that all database tables are created.
I found this information in the post of [Ali Serghini, November 5th, 2010](http://devserghini.blogspot.de/2010/11/android-sqliteopenhelper-and-multiple.html).

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I have found the reason for the strange behaviour:

I think my approach to make the DATABASE_VERSION an external parameter is right, if you have multiple ContentProviders.

I did just forget that there is yet another ContentProvider: A simple ConfigTable to store the settings. I think I hade a mix of different DATABASE_VERSION values in the end, that leads to re-creating the database on every startup.

After referencing a single param from all ContentProviders, everything worked as expected.

Thanks anyway,
Sebastian